# How to apply a simple operation in a matrice with specific columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

On this data frame `DTA` :

```
structure(list(VARIETE = structure(c(6L, 7L, 35L, 13L, 1L, 5L
), .Label = c("ADVISOR", "ALBATOR", "AMBOISE", "APOSTEL", "AUCKLAND", 
"BERGAMO", "CELLULE", "CHEVIGNON", "COMPLICE", "CONCRET", "CREEK", 
"FILON", "FRUCTIDOR", "GEDSER", "HYKING", "HYNVICTUS", "JAIDOR", 
"JOHNSON", "KWS DAKOTANA", "KWS EXTASE", "LEANDRE", "LG ABSALON", 
"LG ANDROID", "LUMINON", "MAORI", "MUTIC", "NEMO", "PASTORAL", 
"RGT CESARIO", "RGT GOLDENO", "RGT LIBRAVO", "RGT PULKO", "RGT SACRAMENTO", 
"RGT VOLUPTO", "RUBISKO", "SANREMO", "SOPHIE CS", "SOVERDO CS", 
"SYSTEM", "TENOR", "TRIOMPH", "UNIK"), class = "factor"), MOY_AJUST_GENE = c(114.7091686, 
113.0905972, 114.4763114, 112.2964094, 115.1946611, 112.9146611
), `2018` = c(112.806868, 110.486868, 115.216868, 112.576868, 
116.666868, 113.036868), `2017` = c(114.6042664, 113.4942664, 
114.8342664, 112.2842664, 115.4242664, 114.3442664), `2016` = c(124.5586416, 
111.2986416, 114.4086416, 110.1586416, 110.3786416, 109.8286416
), `2015` = c(112.2388684, 113.4588684, 114.1988684, 114.5588684, 
118.3088684, 114.4488684), `2014` = c(115.6734024, 114.1534024, 
111.5334024, 111.9034024, NA, NA), `2013` = c(112.1379582, 113.5479582, 
115.5979582, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm looking for a function to apply simples actions :

1) Keep cols `[, 2:(ncol(DTA))] as.numeric` # to avoid further problems

I tried :

```
for(i in c(2, 2:ncol(DTA))) {
  DTA[, i] <- as.numeric(DTA[, i])} # but I'm not convinced
```

2) Apply a second operation on every cells except col 1 `VARIETE` and NAs :

```
moy <- mean(DTA$MOY_AJUST_GENE) # mean of the col 2
```

I want to devide every values of `DTA` by `moy` and multiply by 100 inside of a new data frame:

```
DTA_ecart <- (DTA[, 2:(ncol(DTA))] / moy) *100 # totaly wrong but you know what I need
```

Do you have any solutions, I didn't found a proper way alone with "apply" function. Also, `DTA` will probably change in the futur, so this is why I want to use `[, 2:(ncol(DTA))]`.

Thank you

Comment: hi,
can you post the result of `dput(DTA)` inside your question?
If your data `DTA` is too large you can post `dput(head(DTA))` instead

Comment: It's done with head(DTA)

Comment: it is easier to work with your data if you provide the output of `dput(head(DTA))`

Comment: Sorry, is that you want (edit) ? I've forgoted the dput().

Comment: Did you try `DTA[, 2:(ncol(DTA))] <- DTA[, 2:(ncol(DTA))] / moy * 100`  ?

Comment: It works but how can I create a new object to keep the first one ?

Comment: what do you mean? Do you want another object `DTA1 <- DT` and then do `DTA1[, 2:(ncol(DTA1))] <- DTA1[, 2:(ncol(DTA1))] / moy * 100` ?

Comment: It is what I did :) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dplyr` package: 
there is a `mutate_at` function which allows you to manipulate several columns at once.
In this case I use `mutate_at(-1, ...)` because I want to manipulate every column except the first (you can also reference columns by name or regular expression).

```
   library(dplyr)

    DTA %>% 
      mutate_at(-1, as.numeric) %>%
      mutate_at(-1, ~.x / mean(MOY_AJUST_GENE) * 100)


    VARIETE MOY_AJUST_GENE     2018     2017     2016     2015     2014    2013
1   BERGAMO      100.81637 112.8069 114.6043 124.5586 112.2389 115.6734 112.138
2   CELLULE       99.39383 110.4869 113.4943 111.2986 113.4589 114.1534 113.548
3   RUBISKO      100.61171 115.2169 114.8343 114.4086 114.1989 111.5334 115.598
4 FRUCTIDOR       98.69583 112.5769 112.2843 110.1586 114.5589 111.9034      NA
5   ADVISOR      101.24306 116.6669 115.4243 110.3786 118.3089       NA      NA
6  AUCKLAND       99.23920 113.0369 114.3443 109.8286 114.4489       NA      NA
```

Comment: I think, there is a problem because it only works on the second column. I don't understant this syntax. Should I apply this on every columns ?

Comment: do you want to divide each column by the mean of the second column (i.e `column_3 / mean(column_2)`)  or do you want to divide each column by its own mean ( `column_3 / mean(column_3)`)

Comment: I want to divide each column by the mean of the second one `MOY_AJUST_GENE`

Comment: Then my solution should provide the right answer. Why do you think that it does not work?